# Can AQTime performance profiler profile vcl source?

Tags: performance, delphi, aqtime

I am using Delphi 2007 / XE with AQTime 6.  I wrote a test application that create few TButton instances.  I have turn on necessary compiling and linking switches to make it work with AQTime.

When I attempt to run the application in AQTime with performance profiler, the VCL / RTL classes aren't show in profiling.  Can AQTime performance profile VCL / RTL classes?

Comment: May I respectfully suggest that you contact the developers of AQtime. They are best placed to answer this.

Comment: Thanks. I have and no answer from them yet.

Comment: It looks like you have the answer now :)
http://smartbear.com/forums/forum/post/?mode=singleThread&thread=fc91451e-bbb9-4fd9-93b4-c9c37ff0705c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is answer from Alex of SmartBear (original post: http://smartbear.com/forums/f59/t46450/can-performance-profiler-profile-vcl-source):

> By default, AQtime excludes VCL code from profiling. To profile VCL
>   code, you need to disable this option:  Options | Options... | General
>   | General Preferences | Exclude standard source files
>
> Please note that complete support for RAD Studio XE was implemented
>   only in AQtime 7. I have just checked, and AQtime 6 can profile the
>   VCL code of an XE application just fine, but the source code editor
>   panel may show an incorrect source code snippet for a routine. So, it
>   is best to use version 7 of AQtime for RAD Studio XE applications
>   profiling.

Answer (score 0):

Probably AQTime needs VCL source code, but doesn't know where to find it. I think somewhere in the AQTime there was an ability to specify additional paths to sources.

Comment: The source code location is specified in Project | Search Directories in AQTime.  However, this doesn't seems related to my problem.  When the project is loaded in AQTime, I can't see any StdCtrls modules loaded in AQTime.  The profiling result also doesn't show any code related to TButton.